# Is it possible with DirectX11 to have pixel shader output an integer rather than float4?

Tags: shaders, directx11

I am trying to implement object picking via a shaders.  My intent is to create a texture2d that I would write out ID values describing individual objects.

Following drawing the objects, I would query back the pixel value at the focus point and read out the ID of the object.

I've created my texture2d as follows:

```
// Create a very tiny selection texture.
// This will record the color ID as unique identifier of a selectable object.
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
desc.Width = 1;
desc.Height = 1;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT;  // 16 bit integer, hold up to 65536 possible unique IDs.
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING; // We will write via GPU and read to CPU!
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;

HRESULT result = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&desc, 0, &m_colorRenderTarget);
if (FAILED(result)) {
    OutputDebugString(L"PickRenderer: Unable to create Texture2D");
}
```

Is it possible to then to make a pixel shader that would write out an R32 integer value, rather than the float values for RGBA?  If so, how would I best do this?

My pixel shader currently writes float RGB values out as follows:

```
// A constant buffer that stores the model transform.
cbuffer ModelConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    float4x4    modelToWorld;
    float3      color;  // Instead use unsigned int32 here if possible?
};

// Per-vertex data used as input to the vertex shader.
struct PixelShaderInput
{
    min16float4 pos     : POSITION;
};

// Can this use a different return value for uint?
min16float4 main(PixelShaderInput IN) : SV_TARGET
{
    return min16float4(color, 1.f);
}
```

Thanks, I've been trying to find an answer to this, but it seems very unusual to write out non-float values if it is possible.

Comment: DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT would be 32bit integer, not 16. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I use a uint texture to store material ID's.

The shader output struct I use for this is and the ID constant:

```
uint matID;

struct PixelShaderOutput
{          
 uint RenderMaterialID : SV_Target0;   
};
```

Write to the output targets:

```
PixelShaderOutput PShader(PixelShaderInput input)
{
 PixelShaderOutput output = (PixelShaderOutput) 0;   
 output.RenderMaterialID = matID;  

 return output;
}
```

Then just read back the ID texture at a later stage in your render pipeline

```
Texture2D<uint> RenderMaterialIDs;
uint MatID = RenderMaterialIDs.Load(uint3(globalIdx.x, globalIdx.y, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pixel Shaders output float values that are converted to the appropriate format as they are placed into the Render Target. If you look at [Direct3D feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx), some feature levels support a `UINT` or `SINT` format for a render target. So if you returned `255.0`, it would write `255` into the `UINT` render target.

Otherwise you need to use DirectCompute.